# Calling custom IQueryable extension methods on an IGrouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, extension-methods, iqueryable, igrouping

I have code very much like this:

```
Context.History.GroupBy(d => new { d.Category, d.Month })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Category = group.Key.Category,
        Month = group.Key.Month,
        // Geometric mean:
        Value = Math.Exp(group.Average(a => Math.Log(a.Value)))
    })
    .GroupBy(d => d.Month)
    .Select(monthly => new Dto {
         Month = monthly.Month,
         Average = monthly.Average(a => a.Value)
    });
```

There's a few other places I calculate the geometric mean, so I would like to put that in an extension method, so the line after the comment would look like `Value = group.GeometricMean(a => a.Value)`.

- If I write a regular extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, Entity Framework complains that it can't convert it to a query.
- If I write a method operating on `IQueryable<T>`, I'm informed that `group` is, in fact, not an `IQueryable<T>`, but rather an `IGrouping<TKey, T>`.
- Trying to call it as `Value = group.AsQueryable().GeometricMean(a => a.Value)` leads to an `ArgumentException` saying 'Expression of type IGrouping cannot be used for parameter of type IQueryable (Parameter arg0)'.

It seems to me I must somehow turn that `IGrouping` into `IQueryable` for my extension method to work, but I can't figure out how. There's a few questions on SO that wander near that subject, but none that I've found that are applicable here. It might be that this is simply not supported in EF as of now.

More information: replacing the whole `Select` body with some function is a no-go, as the point is to make the geometric mean calculation reusable - the rest is simply not reusable. It needs to be done in SQL, as it's been shown to be far too slow to fetch the data and do the calculation in C#.

Looking at the source of some `IQueryable` extension methods, it seems the body of the extension method would build up some expression tree and pass that to `source.Provider.Execute`. I think I may already have managed that part, but I've been unable to properly test it due to the above issues.

Comment: As I know, custom aggregates are not supported yet: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22957

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but at least now I know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Before you give up, there Is extension which supports custom aggregates https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: That's not a custom aggregate afaik. Isn't Average supported by EF Core? Also Math.Exp and Math.Log are translatble too, so shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Can you post the code for the extension GeometricMean that you wrote?

Comment: I've written many variations. Here's two: https://gist.github.com/Biotronic/55bab00cc6f9bb52e5d850088c93077a

Comment: @BioTronic is it possible to define the extension on IGrouping instead of IQueryable?

Comment: If I do, it's suddenly an opaque function call rather than an `Expression` which EF is able to operate on. I mean, it seems to be that anyway, but I was hoping the call to `source.Provider.Execute` would give it some magical access.

Comment: Guys, you can do any magic. If translator do not support custom aggregates natively - you will fail. I know complexity.